# How to fix cmake find_package "Could NOT find SDL2" on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sdl-2

I'm working on a small project using SDL2, and I'm using cmake for building and compiling the code so that it work on different platforms (mainly windows and linux). Right now I'm having trouble finding the SDL2 library using the find_package function on windows.

I've already implemented my own FindSDL2.cmake file based on a couple of blogs that were linked to on similar questions to this one, yet it still can't find the SDL2 library.

Another solution I've seen is passing the path where SDL2 is installed to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, but unless I'm missing something, that would mean that if I were to have my code on github and somebody wanted to build it an run it themselves they would also have to pass the path where they installed SDL2, which seems a bit annoying and also isn't what other similar open source projects are doing.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Generic-Fighting-Game VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories("${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable(Generic-Fighting-Game src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Generic-Fighting-Game ${SDL2_LIBRARY})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

And used the FindSDL2.cmake filed found here https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake since I don't know enough about cmake in order to make my own FindSDL2.cmake file

Once I run make on the build directory I get the following error

```
C:\Users\HP\Documents\Generic-Fighting-Game\build>make
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindSDL2.cmake:163 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/HP/Documents/Generic-Fighting-Game/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/HP/Documents/Generic-Fighting-Game/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:604: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

below link FindSDL2.cmake is for unix and mingw.
so, if you running your cmake in window platform, and you might not using mingw the path is wrong, it means not windows format. so cmake can't find library.

https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake

```
SET(SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
)
```

so, make it work around .

set the path to window foramt like C:\ProgramData\Microsoft

and set the path location where your library installed or existed path.